# Multi-Threading Server/Client Chat

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, client, server

So this is my first post here, I am currently trying to make a Java client/server chat application using socket programming.

I currently have the server waiting for a client to connect and then passing the client's messages back to the client. So far I have tried different methods to make the server continuously listen to new clients and connect them allowing them to post and view messages with each other.

Can you point me in the right direction and how I should implement this?

---

### SERVER

> 

```
class TCPServer {
private ServerSocket serverSocket;
private int port;
String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
public TCPServer(int port) {
    this.port = port;
}
public void begin() throws IOException {

    System.out.println("Starting the server at port: " + port);
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

    System.out.println("Waiting for clients... " + newLine);

    try {

        Socket connectionSocket = serverSocket.accept();

        DataOutputStream hello =
                new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
        hello.writeUTF("You have successfully connected!" + newLine + "please type your      username");


        //A client has connected to this server. Get client's username
        String username = getUserName(connectionSocket);
        System.out.println(username + " has connected" + newLine);
        //Start chat method
        startChat(connectionSocket, username);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}

public String getUserName(Socket connectionSocket) throws IOException {
    String clientUserName;
    // ArrayList clients = new ArrayList();


    BufferedReader userNameClient =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            connectionSocket.getInputStream()));


    clientUserName = userNameClient.readLine();
    //clients.add(clientUserName);


    DataOutputStream greetingFromServer =
            new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
    //writeUTF Caused incorrect key codes to appear at beginning of String
    greetingFromServer.writeBytes("Welcome " + clientUserName + ", please type your message" + newLine);


    return clientUserName;
}

public void startChat(Socket connectionSocket, String username) throws IOException {
    String clientSentence;
    String clientMessageOut;



    while (true) {
        //Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();

        BufferedReader inFromClient =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        DataOutputStream outToClient =
                new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());



        //Loops to check if client message is not empty
        while ((clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine()) != null) {
            outToClient.writeBytes(username + ": " + clientSentence + newLine);
            if (clientSentence.equals("close")) {
                System.out.println(username + " has left the server");
            }

        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int port = 6788;

    TCPServer welcomeSocket = new TCPServer(port);
    welcomeSocket.begin();


}
```

}

---

### CLIENT

> 

```
class TCPClient {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String sentence;
    String modifiedSentence;
    boolean keepConnection = true;
    int port = 6788;
    Scanner inFromUser = new Scanner(System.in);

    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 6788);
    //System.out.println("You are connented to server"+ '\n'+"Please enter your username: ");
    String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    //Recieve greeting message
    InputStream messageFromServer = clientSocket.getInputStream();
    DataInputStream in =
            new DataInputStream(messageFromServer);
    System.out.println("FROM SERVER: " + in.readUTF());


    DataOutputStream outToServer =
            new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader inFromServer =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            clientSocket.getInputStream()));

    while ((sentence = inFromUser.nextLine()) != null) {
        outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
        modifiedSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
        System.out.println("sentence = " + sentence);
        System.out.println(modifiedSentence);
        if (sentence.equals("close")) {
            System.out.println("You have left the server");
            outToServer.writeBytes("close" + newLine);
            break;
        }
    }
    clientSocket.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `while(true){}` or `while((socket = serverSocket.accept()) != null)` for the server to loop indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

To make the server able to connect to multiple clients, you can create a loop where you accept new connections:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        Socket connectionSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        ...
    } 
    ...
}
```

To keep it responsive, you can work with each client in a new thread or maintain a thread pool and submit a task to it for each new connection.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example ([taken from ServerSocketEx](http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/io/ServerSocketEx.java)) of how you could do it. ServerSocketEx extends ServerSocket, but this is just for ease of use; all of the code following `super.accept` is relevent to your question.

As others have suggested, you should call accept() in a loop, surrounded by a try { } catch (IOException ...); so that you can shut down if you choose to close the ServerSocket

```
public Socket accept() throws IOException {
    Socket s = super.accept();
    if (getSocketRunnerFactory() != null) {
        SocketRunner runner = getSocketRunnerFactory().createSocketRunner(s);
        if (executor != null) {
            Future f = 
                executor.submit(runner);
            if (futures != null) futures.add(f);
        }
        else {
            Thread t = new Thread(runner);
            t.start();
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```